# Como transcrever funções JavaScript para PHP

Tags: php

Como posso transcrever estas funçoes para PHP?

```
function bytesToWords(bytes) {
    var str;
    for(var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += 2) {
        var char = bytes[i] << 8;
        if (bytes[i + 1])
            char |= bytes[i + 1];
        str += String.fromCharCode(char);
    }
    return str.replace('undefined', '');
}

function bytesFromWords (string) {
    var bytes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var char = string.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes.push(char >>> 8);
        bytes.push(char & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

tenho dúvidas em funçoes tipo a `fromCharCode`, `push` como fazer tal transcriçao?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Siga isto:

- O equivalente de `string.length` seria `strlen($string)` para contar a quantidade de caracteres, para ter compatibilidade com unicode, use:

  ```
  $j = preg_match_all('/.{1}/us', $string, $data);
  ```
- O equivalente de `bytes.length` seria `count($bytes)` para contar a quantidade de itens na array
- O equivalente de `bytes.push(char >>> 8)` seria `$bytes[] = $char >> 8;`
- Para concatenar uma string a uma variável existente em JavaScript usamos `+=`, em PHP usamos `.=`
- O equivalente de `string.charCodeAt` seria `ord(substr($string, $i, 1));`, para compatibilidade com unicode, use:

  ```
  function unicode_ord($char) {
      list (, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
      return $ord;
  }
  ```
- O equivalente `String.fromCharCode(char);` seria `chr($char)`, para compatibilidade com unicode, use:

  ```
  function unicode_chr($u) {
      return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
  }
  ```

Acredito que o código deva ficar assim:

```
<?php
function unicode_ord($char) {
    list (, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
    return $ord;
}

function unicode_chr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}

function bytesToWords($bytes) {
    $str = '';
    $j = count($bytes);

    for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i += 2) {
        $char = $bytes[$i] << 8;
        if ($bytes[$i + 1]) {
            $char |= $bytes[$i + 1];
        }
        $str .= unicode_chr($char);
    }
    return $str;
}

function bytesFromWords($string) {
    $bytes = array();
    $j = preg_match_all('/.{1}/us', $string, $data);
    $data = $data[0];

    for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
        $char = unicode_ord($data[$i]);
        $bytes[] = $char >> 8;
        $bytes[] = $char & 0xFF;
    }
    return $bytes;
}


$data = bytesFromWords('㬁愃膘ƘჀ䚐⦀飠噋&ӡ๨㏃棱쌌ص䌠');

echo implode(', ', $data);
echo bytesToWords($data);
```

---

### Extra

Na versão JavaScript você usou `str.replace('undefined', '');` por que a variável não estava definida, mas o melhor é setar uma valor para variável e assim não irá necessitar do replace, assim:

```
function bytesToWords(bytes) {
    var str = "";//Setado string vazia
    for(var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += 2) {
        var char = bytes[i] << 8;
        if (bytes[i + 1])
            char |= bytes[i + 1];
        str += String.fromCharCode(char);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: aeee, muito obrigado, voce fez muito mais que me ajudar!! Te darei todos os positivos possíveis a mim ;D

Comment: @user3163662 basta participar da comunidade colaborando com respostas e perguntando que já tá bom demais hehehe :) Veja que respondi no SOen também http://stackoverflow.com/a/29786119/1518921 se fizer sentido pra ti, aceita lá, grato!

Comment: Aceitei lá, se puder fazer as honras: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782588/how-transcribe-bytestohex-for-php/29782930#29782930

Comment: Me expressei mal rs, quiz dizer "passa" pra responder se puder :p

Comment: A sim quando eu puder eu passo lá :) ... Boa noite!

Comment: Relaxa haha Boa tarde